# rendering images in rows

Tags: php, html, css

trying to make this code render images in rows all to no avail. I initially tried to use boostrap's row and column classes and it didn't work. Then I tried the table element still no result. could you spot the problrm?

```
// Get images from the database
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");

if($query->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $imageURL = 'uploads/'.$row["file_name"];
?>
   <!-- begin post -->
   <div class="container recent-posts">
   <table>
   <tr>

   <td class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
   <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" />
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
    </td>

<?php }
}
else{ ?>
    <p>No image(s) found...</p>
<?php } ?> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</div>
```

Comment: You're creating a `.container` and table for every entry. Start your container/table outside of the loop, render each individual element inside the loop. fyi, `</tr></table></div>` should not be outside either

Comment: Don't use tables for layout, that's a 1990s approach. It's inflexible and un-semantic. Tables are for presenting data, not organising your page. Look into CSS flexbox or grid - you can create your rows and columns quite easily _and_ it's responsive by default.

Comment: please @brombeer include the code to your ans

Comment: @jonathan22345 could you not make an attempt based on the description of what you need to change? Follow the instructions, try it. If it's still not working, update your question with the new code and explain the new issue.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? What **exactly** did not work? Is this a PHP problem, a HTML problem, or a CSS problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've swapped in your db code for an array and foreach, but it is in the same spirit.

Use indentation, to help you get your loops and tags in order.

```
<?php

$images = [
    ['file_name' => 'foo.jpg'],
    ['file_name' => 'bar.jpg'],
    ['file_name' => 'baz.jpg'],
]
?>
<html>
    <?php if(!empty($images)) { ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach($images as $row) { $imageURL = 'uploads/'.$row["file_name"]; ?>
                    <td class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" />
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p>No image(s) found...</p>
    <?php } ?>
</html>
```

As others have said, there isn't anything really to be gained here by using a table.

Comment: Feel free to link/edit to a better way of displaying images in a line/row after the adjusted code.

Answer (score -1):

Does it show you the rest of the html elements or does it show you the message that there is no picture?

Check with the inspect tool what location the src attribute of the img element is.

You can add a backslash in the $imageURL variable

```
$imageURL = '/uploads/' . $row["file_name"];
```

Show us the structure and a record of the images table.

Give us more details about what happens when the page is loaded. Like what it loading in your page.

I suggest you ditch the tables and use boostrap instead.

Example here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

Comment: Don't use an answer to request more information. That's what comments are for.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular at that moment i don't have enough reputation to comment.